# How to start an independent gnuplot process with either subprocess or QProcess?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, gnuplot, qprocess

There are already a lot of questions and answers about `subprocess` and `QProcess`, but I haven't found yet an answer to my issue. So, please forgive if I haven't found the answer in this bulk of partly confusing or outdated answers.

It sounds like a simple task: In a PyQt GUI application I want to start a independent (sub)process.
In my case: gnuplot, a plotting tool, with the option '-p' (persistent, i.e. keep window open when the plot is done). Once started, it should continue to run as a independent (interactive) application.

The documentation of
[`QProcess`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start) and [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html) didn't help me further.

**Code:** (My condensed minimal example, which does not work as expected)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QProcess
import sys, subprocess

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(0,0,700,500)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.pb_plot_1 = QPushButton("Plot via subprocess")
        self.pb_plot_1.clicked.connect(self.on_click_pb_plot_1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pb_plot_1)

        self.pb_plot_2 = QPushButton("Plot via QProcess")
        self.pb_plot_2.clicked.connect(self.on_click_pb_plot_2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pb_plot_2)
        
        self.pb_plot_3 = QPushButton("Plot via QProcess and loading a file")
        self.pb_plot_3.clicked.connect(self.on_click_pb_plot_3)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pb_plot_3)
        
        self.setLayout(self.layout) 
        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    
    def get_plot_code(self):
        return '''
        # some gnuplot code, in reality much longer
        set term wxt
        plot sin(x)
        '''
        
    def on_click_pb_plot_1(self):
        gnuplotPath = r'gnuplot\bin\gnuplot'
        gnuplotCode = self.get_plot_code()
        proc = subprocess.Popen([gnuplotPath, '-p'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        proc.communicate(gnuplotCode.encode())

    def on_click_pb_plot_2(self):
        gnuplotPath = r'gnuplot\bin\gnuplot'
        gnuplotCode = self.get_plot_code()
        proc = QProcess(self)
        proc.start(gnuplotPath, ["-p"])
        proc.write(gnuplotCode.encode())
     
    def on_click_pb_plot_3(self):
        gnuplotPath = r'gnuplot\bin\gnuplot'
        gnuplotFile = 'gnuplotFile.gp'
        proc = QProcess(self)
        proc.start(gnuplotPath, ["-p", gnuplotFile])
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Result:**

If I press on the buttons, each time gnuplot will be opened and the graph will be displayed. So far, OK.
However,

***via subprocess:*** gnuplot will work as interactive window, but my PyQt application will freeze (not responding) until I close gnuplot.
With [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) there seems the option `close_fds=True`, which should probably do what I want, but in Windows this doesn't seem to work together with sending commands via `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`.

> Note that on Windows, you cannot set close_fds to true and also
> redirect the standard handles by setting stdin, stdout or stderr

So, how else would I do it with `subprocess`? Adding `proc.terminate()` will not help.

***via QProcess:***   gnuplot will freeze and will not work as interactive window (not responding). If I kill gnuplot I can start over again but gnuplot again will freeze.

I also have tried something like `startDetached()`, etc...  without success...

I can imagine that the issue can be solved by a tiny change in the code. But I don't know how to change.
So, I'm sure it is my limited understanding of the documentation and that I'm missing suitable examples.
My configuration: Win10, Python 3.6.3, PyQt 5.11.3

**Update**: (code changed above, 3rd variation added)

***via QProcess and reading a file*** (instead of writing code to gnuplot)

a) gnuplot will create the plot, b) nothing will freeze, c) gnuplot stays interactive, d) I can independently close either my application or gnuplot.
*However,* I don't want to read a gnuplot file from disk, but I want to send code to gnuplot (to `stdin` I assume).

**Update 2:**

Maybe this could be a hint to somebody who could explain this. It seems to depend on the gnuplot version. Following results:

```
5.2.0 QWindowsPipeWriter::write failed. (The handle is invalid.)
5.2.2 QWindowsPipeWriter::write failed. (The handle is invalid.)
5.2.3 QWindowsPipeWriter::write failed. (The handle is invalid.)
5.2.4 QWindowsPipeWriter::write failed. (The handle is invalid.)
5.2.5 QWindowsPipeWriter::write failed. (The handle is invalid.)

5.2.6 works
5.2.7 works
5.2.8 works

5.4.0 freezing
5.4.1 freezing
```

Comment: I did not observe it freeze using QProcess or subprocess in Linux, python 3.9.5 and PyQt5 5.15.4

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks for checking. Hmm, then again an annoying Windows special case?

Comment: What you indicate seems strange to me since QProcess should not block anything, is the code you provide the one that generates the freeze or have you used another code?

Comment: @eyllanesc I used exactly this code. So, could it be a gnuplot specific "problem" under Windows? I will modify the answer and add another observation.

Comment: mmm, QProcess shouldn't block anything so it seems strange to me. Try more recent versions of PyQt5 as it may be a bug

Comment: What happens if you change `proc.write(gnuplotCode.encode())` with `QTimer.singleShot(1000, lambda p=proc, code=gnuplotCode: p.write(code.encode()))`? I just want to rule out a possible behavior in windows

Comment: @eyllanesc the same thing. gnuplot will freeze.

Comment: 1) Does gnuplot freeze by itself or does it also freeze the pyqt5 window? 2) If you change 1000 to 5000, does the same thing happen?

Comment: @eyllanesc in this case it looks like only gnuplot is freezing. Doesn't matter if 1000 or 5000. I can still use PyQt5 window and even start another gnuplot process with `subprocess` in parallel. So, looks like gnuplot is waiting for something...?

Comment: try change with:  `proc.write((gnuplotCode + "\n").encode())`

Comment: @eyllanesc that's what I've also already tried. This can help if you have a command, e.g. `plot x` without newline. But my gnuplotCode above already has a newline at the end. An additional one does not help.

Comment: mmm, try change `set term wxt` to `set term qt`

Comment: @eyllanesc same freezing with qt terminal. So, if it works fine for you under Linux it seems to be a specific Windows problem, or combination of Windows and gnuplot. If nobody else on Windows can reproduce this, then it might even my configuration of Windows?! Or even a gnuplot version issue? I'm running gnuplot 5.4.1

Comment: @eyllanesc hmm, seems to be a specific gnuplot issue (probably in combination with Windows). With gnuplot 5.4.1 it freezes, but with 5.2.6 is seems to work fine, with 5.2.0 I get an error `QWindowsPipeWriter::write failed. (The handle is invalid.)` . I will add this to the question.

Comment: @eyllanesc your suspicion was correct. With a PyQt5 5.15.4 this problem doesn't seem to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, @eyllanesc was right...  I updated PyQt5 from 5.11.3 to 5.15.4 and the problem doesn't seem to appear anymore. Whatever bug or incompatibility this was...